# Syntax error near 'unlock' - 'alter role warehouse_user unlock'

Tags: sybase, sqlanywhere, sap-iq

Trying to run  -  'alter role warehouse_user unlock' on Sybase IQ

Failed due to
SQL Anywhere Error -131: Syntax error near 'unlock' on line 1

someone knows why?

Comment: I found [this older information](https://sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com/questions/17290/how-to-manually-unlock-a-locked-user-account-in-sqla16) that claims a different `ALTER` command to unlock accounts, if it may possibly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `alter role` statement doesn't appear to have anything to do with locked users (or roles):

- [IQ - ALTER ROLE statement](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_IQ/a898e08b84f21015969fa437e89860c8/a440f8f584f21015a7799249d201ff8e.html?locale=en-US)
- [SQLAnywhere - ALTER ROLE statement](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_SQL_Anywhere/93079d4ba8e44920ae63ffb4def91f5b/81697c886ce21014ba0aafbbe682815c.html?locale=en-US)

Assuming the objective is to unlock a user account ... older versions of `IQ` (eg, `12.6`, `12.7`) had a stored proc named `sp_iqlocklogin` (currently unable to find an online reference); this proc appears to have been deprecated in favor of the `alter user` statement:

- `alter user <user_id> reset login policy`
- [IQ - Unlocking User Accounts](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_IQ/a89a0a8384f21015b1e7adbeca456f73/a73d894b84f210159f76fb50576f58cc.html?locale=en-US)
- [SQLAnywhere - ALTER USER statement](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_SQL_Anywhere/93079d4ba8e44920ae63ffb4def91f5b/816a02336ce21014875dd5b19aae3228.html?locale=en-US)